# Mercury SMTP client E generates an error.  How can I resolve this?

Tags: email, smtp

Error:

> The IP you are using is not authorized" generated by mercury/32 mail server

When I send emails to Gmail it generate this error but when I send mail to my ISP provided email, it is sent successfully.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Mercury since the days of Netware 3, but I guess your problem is that you have to configure it for SMTP auth if you want to send mail via GMail, because of course GMail is *not* an open relay and not meant for submission from a server. There should be some kind of configuration option for that in Mercury.

Please note that GMail will rewrite the FROM address of all mails sent with it to the corresponding GMail account.

Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: thanks for reply, but you are talking about relaying but i am receiving error when using end to end delivery. is this because i have a dynamic public IP ?

Comment: If you try to send mails directly from a dynamic/dialup address, you are basically out of luck, this isn't working anymore for at least a decade because of spam protection reasons. You'll need to relay your mail through your provider, otherwise many receiving mailers will simply reject to talk to your server.